# Getting the total documents that is relevant to a value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm quite new to mongodb so please pardon my obliviousness.
A sample of my database is provided below :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db82583d5b9f0a47c3db6f"),
    "People" : [
            "Ivar Zapp"
    ],
    "Link" : [
            "https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/19/1971280_panama-costa-rica-cuba-111104-.html"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db82583d5b9f0a47c3db70"),
    "People" : [
            "Ivar Zapp"
    ],
    "Link" : [
            "https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/87/872609_panama-costa-rica-cuba-111104-.html"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db82583d5b9f0a47c3db71"),
    "People" : [
            "Ivar Zapp"
    ],
    "Link" : [
            "https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/19/1964024_-latam-centam-brief-111104-.html"
    ]
}
```

My question now is, according to the snippet above, how do I get the count of the link relevant to a person's name? Example output below :

```
{
    "People" : "Ivar Zapp",
    "link_Count" : "3"
}
```

I've thought of aggregation, but I can't really seem to figure out a solution using aggregation for quite a while now. I'm open to any solutions or feedback as long as it helps me progress just a tad bit. Any solutions or feedback provided is most appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $group operations:
You try following command,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: '$People',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        People: '$_id',
        count: 1
    }}
    ]);
```

Output :

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "People": ["Ivar Zapp"]
}
```